# Creating Google Cloud OS image error "file inside the tar archive should be named ''disk.raw''

Tags: iso-image, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to install a [custom Debian image that comes packed with a VoIP solution](https://irontec.github.io/ivozprovider/en/artemis/basic_concepts/installation/cd_install.html#automatic-iso-cd-image) (ISO format).
I've uploaded this ISO file to a bucket in Google, and then attempted to create an image off of it by running this line:

```
$ gcloud compute images create ivoz --project=root-grammar-414115 --source-uri=https://storage.googleapis.com/voip-2990/ivoz.tar.gz
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The file inside the tar archive was named ''README.html''. It should be named ''disk.raw''.
```

I've read Google's documentation about creating images from head to toe, and could not find any indication that any file should be named `disk.raw`, also, which file? The `tar.gz` file that Google requires me to create for the image has a lot of files in it.

Anyone can provide any pointers as to how to continue from here?

Thanks in advance!